# Broadcast change event with Kendo MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to broadcast the kendo combobox change event to other client side layers.
Does kendo have any way like scope.emit or scope.broadcast which is present in angular that broadcast any event.
I have multiple layers on my client side and 1 layer has all the kendo observables, these observables are bind to html, event are also bind to VM, is it possible that I can broadcast this change event. Any inputs to this will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A search into the Documentation and I got this example at Telerik:

Use **(selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"**

```
 @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
        <kendo-combobox [data]="data"
          [filterable]="true"
          (valueChange)="valueChange($event)"
          (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)"
          (filterChange)="filterChange($event)"
          (open)="open()"
          (close)="close()"
          (focus)="focus()"
          (blur)="blur()"
        >
        </kendo-combobox>
        <event-log title="Event log" [events]="events">
        </event-log>
      `
    })
```

Inside your export class:

```
public selectionChange(value: any): void {
    this.log('selectionChange', value);
}
```

For a list of events check this:

**https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/**

Answer (score 0):

You should call the [set method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject/methods/set) that will trigger the change event.